# What is the meaning of "me" in ipfw rules?

Tags: firewalls, terminology

ipfw is an IP firewall and traffic shaper control program.

The term "me" appears on `ipfw` statements like below:

```
ipfw add 02050 allow tcp from me to any out
```

I would like to know exactly what "me" means here.

A man page defines "me" as

```
me: matches any IP address configured on an interface in the system.
The address list is evaluated at the time the packet is analysed.
```

Regarding the phrase "configured ... in the system", which system is it talking about?  Is it talking about the local computer that contains the current directory in which the `ipfw` command is running, as opposed to a remote computer?

Regarding the phrase "configured on an interface in the system", what does it mean by an "interface"?  Examples of interfaces familiar to me are keyboards, mice, and display monitors.  However, I do not think that the man page is talking about keyboards, mice, or monitors.

Comment: why would "me" refer to a separate system?

Comment: Do you know what an IP address is? That might clear up a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

"me" means the system `ipfw` is running on. "Itself". The thing that `ipfw` affects.

"interface" means "network interface", not "user interface". Network interfaces get IP addresses, not keyboards.

Comment: I'm sure one of these days keyboards will start getting IP addresses as well...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling and then that will be connected to a networking interface